# Testing blobstore image post

Tags: python-2.7, google-app-engine, blobstore

I'm testing a post request which contains an image, after the post request if succesfull i receive a url like

```
http://testbed.example.com/_ah/upload/agx0ZXN0YmVkLXRlc3RyGwsSFV9fQmxvYlVwbG9hZFNlc3Npb25fXxgDDA
```

as i already tried and checked in stackoverflow, this wont work to try to upload the image

i have a handler in a route like "/upload/image"

and the code looks like:

```
class UploadScreenshot(webapp2.RequestHandler, blobstore_handlers.BlobstoreUploadHandler):
    def post(self):
        try:
            upload_screenshot = self.get_uploads('file')
            upload_url = self.request.get('upload_url')
            fbkey = self.request.get('fbkey')
            screenshotKey = upload_screenshot[0].key()
            feedback = N.FeedbackModel.query(N.FeedbackModel.fbkey == fbkey)
            feedback.screenshotBlobID = screenshotKey
            feedback.put()
        except:
            self.error(400)
```

what could i do to upload to the Blobstore, i have my app in appspot also but i wanna test this before deploying

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you got things a bit backwards. By the time your UploadScreenshot handler is called the blob should be already uploaded and your handler can access it using the blob key (which you have in screenshotKey). You can't (re)use the upload url at this point (it should have been already used when the user submited the upload form).

You may want to revisit [the blob upload procedure/example](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/blobstore/#Python_Uploading_a_blob).

BTW, this can be fully tested on the development server, the upload URL you get will be a localhost one and the blob is stored on localhost as well.